# Matplotlib X Axis leaving one name off

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im using two lists to populate a simple line plot in matplotlib:

X axis = results[] and the 
Y axis = names[]

Here is what 'names' contains:
['RF', 'GBR', 'KNN', 'CART', 'SVM', 'NN', 'ADA']

and here is what 'results' contains:

[0.8941514126644701,
 0.8821308167746561,
 0.7864150401953114,
 0.812054320544109,
 0.14266745822021032,
 0.7439163675782782,
 0.7350927779887548]

Im using a simple layout for the plot as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()
```

but my plot is short by one element of the list; here is what it looks like:

[image]

what am I missing here?

Comment: What is my_xticks?

Comment: sorry - I left it in by accident (its wasnt causing the issue). post has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the labels without setting the ticks. Either you specify both or none.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(results)
ax.set_xticks(list(range(len(results))))
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()
```

Or

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(names, results)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ax.get_xticks()` tells us that matplotlib is showing ticks at the following locations:

```
[-1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
```

This means that the first label is appearing at -1 on the horizontal axis, off the left side of the chart.  Add the following line after the call to `plot` to set the locations of the ticks and make the labels line up:

```
ax.set_xticks(range(len(names)))
```